# Roblox Studio (Lua) - Loading Data (Not Working)

Tags: lua, roblox, datastore

This is my datastore script, it has leaderstats incorporated. I an trying to save & load the Clicks and the Rebirths that the player accumulated. When I leave it told me that the data was saved but when I join there Isn't any data loaded
Can someone please help me, tell me what am i doing wrong?
I also have "Enable Studio Acces to API Services" set to enabled. This problem persists with every other script i use.

```
local DataStoreService = game:GetService("DataStoreService")
local PlayerData = DataStoreService:GetDataStore("Data_2") -- Change the string value inbetween the "" to reset/change data stores
local LoadData = true -- Don't edit
local CreateData = true -- Don't edit

local function OnPlayerJoin(player)
 
    local Leaderstats = Instance.new("Folder")
    Leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"
    Leaderstats.Parent = player

    local Clicks = Instance.new("IntValue")
    Clicks.Name = "Clicks"
    Clicks.Parent = Leaderstats

    local Rebirths = Instance.new("IntValue")
    Rebirths.Name = "Rebirths"
    Rebirths.Parent = Leaderstats
    
    local PlayerUserId = "Player_"..player.UserId
    local data = PlayerData:GetAsync(PlayerUserId)

    if data and LoadData == true then 
        warn("Loading "..PlayerUserId.." Data!")

        Clicks.Value = data["Clicks"]
        Rebirths.Value = data["Rebirths"]
        
        print("Loaded "..PlayerUserId.." Data! ")
    elseif CreateData == true then
        warn("Creating "..PlayerUserId.." Data!")

        Clicks.Value = 0
        Rebirths.Value = 0
        
        print("Created "..PlayerUserId.." Data! ")
    else
        warn("Check StoreData and CreateData, they may be off! ⚠️")
    end
end

local function create_table(player)
    local player_stats = {}
    for _, stat in pairs(player.leaderstats:GetChildren()) do
        player_stats[stat.Name] = stat.Value
    end
    return player_stats
end

local function OnPlayerExit(player)
    local player_stats = create_table(player)
    local success, err = pcall(function()
        local PlayerUserId = "Player_"..player.UserId
        PlayerData:SetAsync(PlayerUserId, player_stats)
        print("Data Save Success!")
    end)

    if not success then
        warn("Data Save Has Failed! ⚠️")
        local PlayerUserId = "Player_"..player.UserId
        PlayerData:SetAsync(PlayerUserId, player_stats)
        warn("Retrying Data Save! ⚠️")
    end
end

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(OnPlayerJoin)
game.Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(OnPlayerExit)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know are you in roblox or roblox studio, but data store only works in roblox. Also, data can only be load in ServerScriptService using script (Not local script and module script)